# How to get sum by MonthYear in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
 id            Date             Amount

  1   2016-09-29 09:25:37.000    25.13 
  2   2016-08-01 17:20:39.000   598.00
  3   2016-09-29 09:24:47.000    15.60
  4   2016-07-28 17:50:11.000    61.80    
  5   2016-07-28 17:53:56.000    31.40
  6   2016-07-22 10:40:27.000    74.16
```

I'm trying to get two columns like this,

```
MonthYear            Total

Sep 2016             40.73 
Aug 2016            598.00
Jul 2016            167.36
```

But, I want to get most recent year and month to top.

Comment: This is an ordinary sum with group by / order by statement.

Comment: Sum all the amounts / numbers, group the other data except amounts / numbers and order it to display accordingly depending on your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this sql,

```
  SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(4), Date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), Date, 120) 
      AS MonthYear, SUM(Amount) 
      AS Total,
          CAST(CONVERT(varchar(4), Date, 120) AS int) 
      AS Year, DATEPART(m, Date) As Month
    FROM your_table 
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(4), Date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), Date,120),CAST(CONVERT(varchar(4), Date, 120) AS int), DATEPART(m, Date)
ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
   SELECT Datename(MONTH, [Date]) month_name,
       Year([Date]) year,
       Sum([Amount]),
       Month([date]) month_no
FROM   #Table1
GROUP  BY Datename(MONTH, [Date]),
          Year([Date]),
          Month([date])
ORDER  BY Month([date]) DESC,
          Year([Date]),
          Datename(MONTH, [Date])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an other perspective.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.[MonthYear], SUM(t.[Amount]) AS [Total] FROM(
    SELECT RIGHT((CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [Date], 106)), 8) as [MonthYear], [Amount]
    FROM [your_table_name]
)t
GROUP BY t.[MonthYear];
```